# glmnet caret in R - How to check binary logistic LASSO model performance without error?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret, glmnet, lasso-regression

I'm trying to use R's caret and glmnet packages to run LASSO to determine the best predictors for a binary outcome of interest.

I get all the way to checking the trained model's performance (pulling root mean squared error and R-squared values from the predictions), and I get the following error:

**Error in cor(obs, pred, use = ifelse(na.rm, "complete.obs", "everything")) : 'x' must be numeric**

Will anyone please help me figure out why my code is throwing this error? How can I successfully pull the RMSE and R^2 values?

The example code below throws the same error. I'm including all my steps, so you can see how I'm thinking through the LASSO regression. If you want to skip to the end, the final chunk is the problem.

```
set.seed(12345)

# Create toy data frame
toydata = data.frame(status = factor(sample(c('pos', 'neg'), 100, replace=TRUE)),
                x1=runif(100, 1, 15),
                x2=runif(100, 1, 15),
                x3 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x4 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x5 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x6 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x7 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x8 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x9 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x10 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x11 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x12 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x13 = runif(100, 1, 15),
                x14 = runif(100, 1, 15))
```

```
### Partition the data
library(caret)

set.seed(12345)

# Partition (split) and create index matrix of selected values
index <- createDataPartition(toydata$status,
                             p = .8, # 80% of cases assigned to object
                             list = FALSE, # Want a matrix, not a list
                             times = 1) # Only split data once


# Create training and test data frames
train <- toydata[index,] # Select values df2_LASSO by rows in index object
test <- toydata[-index,] # Retain only cases NOT in index matrix
```

```
# Specify k-fold cross-validation as a training method (framework)
ctrlspecs <- trainControl(method = "cv", # Cross-validation
                          number = 2, # Specify number of folds
                          savePredictions = "all") # Save all predictions
```

```
### Specify & Train LASSO Regression Model

# Create a vector of potential lambda values
  # Range provided here is kind of overkill, but good for refinement.
lambda_vector <- 10^seq(5,-5, length=500)


set.seed(12345)

# Specify LASSO regression model to be estimated using the training data and 2-fold cross-validation framework/process

model_LASSO <- train(status ~ ., # . means "all others vectors"
                     data = train,
                     preProcess = c("center","scale"), # Grand mean center and standardize variables
                     method = "glmnet", # Method for LASSO regression
                     tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1, # Mixing percentage. Constant
                                            lambda = lambda_vector), # DF for model to test tuning parameters
                     trControl = ctrlspecs, # Train LASSO using k-fold cross-validation
                     na.action = na.omit, # If NAs encountered, use listwise deletion.
                     family = "binomial")
```

```
# Best (optimal) tuning parameters (alpha, lambda)
  # Optimal lambda = 0.03524473
    # Best tuning parameter to minimize the root mean squared error (RMSE) of model
model_LASSO$bestTune
model_LASSO$bestTune$lambda # Directly access best lambda

# LASSO regression model coefficients (parameter estimates)
coef(model_LASSO$finalModel, # Select the final model coefficients
     model_LASSO$bestTune$lambda) # at the best lambda value

# Plot log(lambda) & RMSE
plot(log(model_LASSO$results$lambda),
     model_LASSO$results$RMSE,
     xlab = "log(lambda)",
     ylab = "RMSE")

# Variable importance
varImp(model_LASSO)

# Data visualization of variable importance
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(varImp(model_LASSO))
```

```
### Model prediction
  # Goal: See how well our model predicts when we give it new data
predictions_LASSO <- predict(model_LASSO, # Use trained model
                             newdata = test) # To predict outcome with test data

# Model performance/accuracy
model_LASSO_perf <- data.frame(RMSE = RMSE(predictions_LASSO, 
                                           test$status),
                               Rsquared = R2(predictions_LASSO,
                                             test$status))
```

Comment: Do you know if we can feed a dataframe containing factor variables directly to the train() function from caret, or do we need to turn them into dummies first?

Comment: It is my understanding that when calling train() on a dataset containing factor variables, they are automatically transformed into a set of dummy variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens just because RMSE and R-squared are meaningless for factor outcomes. You have to use `caret::confusionMatrix` or convert factor to integer (not a so good option in my opinion):

```
confusionMatrix(predictions_LASSO,test$status)

model_LASSO_perf <- data.frame(RMSE = RMSE(as.integer(predictions_LASSO), 
                                           as.integer(test$status)),
                               Rsquared = R2(as.integer(predictions_LASSO),
                                             as.integer(test$status)))
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Then how do we test the accuracy of a logistic LASSO model (binary outcome variable)?

Comment: As said, usually performance for classification problems (binary or not) is evaluated in terms of a number of different metrics depending on the characteristics of the data (in particular, if the classes of the outcome are unbalanced) calculated from the confusion matrix. An example of such metrics are Overall accuracy, KIA, Precision, Recall, F1, MCC ecc..